# Esempi di uso del verbo "impostare"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Conosco il verbo "impostare", ma ho sempre trovato difficile capire come usarlo in modo corretto. Intendo l'accezione di "impostare" che non si riferisce a un’opera muraria, né alla voce di un cantante, né all'atteggiamento di una persona. Non mi riferisco neanche a quella che ha a che vedere con la posta. Cioè, secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impostare1/):

> Determinare preventivamente un modo ordinato di procedere per giungere a una realizzazione concreta o a una soluzione: *i. un lavoro*, gettarne le basi, disporre le varie parti secondo il disegno e le misure prestabilite, in modo da rendere più facile e spedita l’esecuzione; *i. la pagina di un giornale*, stabilire e sistemare la disposizione degli articoli e dei titoli; *i. un problema, i. una questione*, fissare i dati di fatto e precisare gli elementi da chiarire, le difficoltà da appianare e il fine a cui si tende; nel linguaggio finanz., *i. una spesa in bilancio*, iscriverla nei varî capitoli di bilancio.

Per esempio, ho trovato questa frase riferita a una sveglia che suona sempre alle 7 di mattina:

> La **imposto** sempre per altri 5 minuti, ma schiaccio sempre il bottone “snooze” per altri 30 minuti.

L'ho tratta di un frammento di un libro per Kindle che si può scaricare liberamente come mostra del testo. Per cominciare, non capisco del tutto l'uso che si fa qui del verbo "impostare". Immagino che significhi che si fa in modo che la sveglia suoni di nuovo entro cinque minuti.

Potreste spiegarmi come e perché si usa il verbo "impostare" nella frase precedente? Potreste farmi  e spiegarmi altri esempi di uso di "impostare" nel linguaggio comune?

Comment: Il libro è in italiano o è una traduzione? Mi sembra che qui "impostare" significhi "regolare". Lo stesso si può dire ad esempio per l'accensione del riscaldamento: "Ho impostato la caldaia: il riscaldamento sarà acceso dalle 18 alle 24" (Solo due piccole note: meglio dire "non capisco del tutto" oppure "non capisco bene" e "l'uso che si fa qui del verbo", senza il "ne")

Comment: Infatti, questo uso di “impostare” corrisponde un po' all'inglese “to set” (e tutto sommato rientra in senso lato in «Determinare preventivamente un modo ordinato di procedere per giungere a una realizzazione concreta o a una soluzione»). Comunque, il brano sembra una traduzione non molto ben fatta: a parte la ripetizione di “sempre”, “l'allarme” (alarm clock) in italiano si chiama “sveglia”, e comunque è maschile ma poi è concordato con un pronome femminile (“la imposto”).

Comment: Anche "7 della mattina" sembra un anglismo... E il tasto "snooze", se non sbaglio, è "posponi", o qualcosa del genere.

Comment: @Benedetta: In teoria si tratta di un libro per imparare l'italiano, questo: https://www.amazon.es/gp/aw/d/B00S5B73ZG?pc_redir=T1&tag=cp0d-21! Per curiosità, ho letto un po' del frammento che si poteva scaricare come mostra.

Comment: @Benedetta: Ho fatto il paio di correzioni che mi hai indicato. Grazie mille!

Comment: Benedetta e @DaG: Non mi andava di citare quel testo pieno di scorrettezze nel corpo della mia domanda, quindi ho lasciato soltanto la frase col verbo "impostare".

Comment: @Benedetta: Forse non è tanto grave dire «il tasto "snooze"» se la scritta "snooze" appare veramente su questo tasto. Le sveglie che si trovano nel mio paese di solito sono così e immagino sia lo stesso in Italia.

Comment: @Benedetta: L'esempio che hai fatto con la caldaia è perfetto per includerlo in una risposta alla mia domanda. Mi piacerebbe avere alcuni esempi di questo tipo per capire meglio come usare questo verbo nel linguaggio comune.

Comment: Non preoccuparvi: non leggerò quel libro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specie quando ci si riferisce ad oggetti di tecnologia, *impostare* assume sovente il significato di *configurare* come nell'inglese *to set up*, o di *regolare* (verbo).

Ora non posso fornire riferimenti bibliografici, ma gli esempi di questo utilizzo sono ben frequenti nel parlato:

> Imposto la destinazione nel navigatore e poi partiamo.
>
> Marco impostò il termostato a 20°C.
>
> Dopo il decollo, il pilota automatico viene solitamente impostato per raggiungere e mantenere un'altitudine di 28000 piedi.

Come ulteriore esempio, in gran parte delle applicazioni per computer e dei sistemi operativi, il menù che permette di personalizzare il funzionamento degli stessi è denominato proprio *impostazioni*, usato come sinonimo di *preferenze* o *opzioni*.

Si tratta solo di una mia ipotesi, ma questo utilizzo del verbo *impostare* potrebbe essere proprio un calco di *to set up*, dato che è presente solo in campi semantici di nascita relativamente moderna come quelli dell'elettronica o dell'informatica, che sono composti in gran misura da termini prestati o ricalcati dall'inglese.

Per quanto riguarda il fatto che la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impostare1/) non faccia menzione esplicita di quest'uso, suppongo come già proposto da @DaG nel suo commento che esso venga fatto ricadere nel caso 1.b:

> disporre le varie parti secondo il disegno e le misure prestabilite

In alternativa, potrebbe essere un'estensione del caso 2 agli oggetti inanimati oltre che alle persone:

> Atteggiare la persona nel modo più conveniente per compiere una determinata azione

Quindi preparare un dispositivo nel modo più appropriato per compiere una determinata azione (scaldare una stanza, pilotare un aereo)

Entrambe le spiegazioni mi sembrano egualmente plausibili.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie mille della risposta!

Comment: Ti ringrazio del benvenuto, partecipare ad un SE è sempre un piacere.